# Как хранить фотографии в БД

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Я так понимаю, что надо их хранить в виде таблицы.

```
 user | path           | остальные поля
 123 | images/7493.png
 123 | images/57759.png
 124 | images/23441.png
 123 | images/46532.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хранить их стоит в виде другой таблицы:

```
user_id | image_id
```

Где image_id - `INT`, генерящийся уникальным для каждой картинки (в простейшем варианте - `auto_increment`). Ну и сохранять картинки, соответственно, с именами вида `{IMAGES_PATH}/image_id.png`, где `{IMAGES_PATH}` - путь из конфига, `image_id` - из таблицы. Если картинки могут быть не только в PNG, то добавить третье поле (тип картинки), а можно ещё и width/height (если они не заданы жёстко ), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Можно в блобе хранить также, или base64encode текстом.

Comment: а лучше всего как?

Comment: Зависит от задачи. Ваш вариант наверное самый быстрый с точки зрения добавления/удаления ну и распределения. В блобах и текстом - медленнее, но файлы реально лежат в базе и гарантирует что если запись о файле есть, то и сам файл есть. Ну и перенос базы и бекапы - тоже целостные.

Comment: Пихая содержимое БД вы создаете дополнительную нагрузку на ресурс, ведь для того, чтобы в вашем случае извлечь фотографию, нужно установить подключение к БД, отправить запрос на получение нужного контента, получить этот контент в своей программе. 

Если вы хотите организовать галерею таким образом, то первая проблема, с которой вы столкнетесь - это превышение количества одновременных подключений к БД.

Фотографии должны храниться в файловой системе, а в БД только пути до них, и если нужно, какая нибудь служебная инфа, но не более!

Comment: @nolka, Какой максимализм! Вы видимо знаете только одну БД? Ну да не об этом. Я в комментарии тезисы описал, дальше зависит от задачи. С Вашей категоричностью не согласен - ситуации разные бывают, а превышение коннекций - несколько бред.